# Android mask a bitmap with a transparent png

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image, bitmapfactory

I have a png image with some transparent areas (like gradient-transparent) and I'd like to "add" this image to over a Bitmap and create a new Bitmap from these two.

is this possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="sliding banner here" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slider_des"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="text"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        />

    </FrameLayout>
```

The above code can be modified to achieve what you want! the first imageview would be for your bitmap and 2nd for overlapping image view that you can placeyour transparent png in.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont need to show them at the same time, rather than create an actual image file from the two!